# How can I prevent prettier behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript, prettier

i want formating like this

```js
  @Matches(
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/,{
      message: 'Please try again'
    })
```

Prettier reformat to

```js
  @Matches(
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/,
    {
      message: 'Please try again'
    }
  )
```

I dont want to disable prettier, i have .prettierrc file in root for configuration

Comment: Webstom plugin.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible without rewriting the whole plugin https://stackoverflow.com/a/75833628/340760

Answer (score 1):

To exclude files from formatting, add entries to a .prettierignore file in the project root or set the --ignore-path CLI option. .prettierignore uses gitignore syntax.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont want to disable prettier, i have .prettierrc file in root for configuration

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the `.prettierignore` file in the root folder.

Comment: I dont want to disable prettier, i have .prettierrc file in root for configuration

Comment: Both answers point to the same solution. They are not saying to disable it, but to add a `.prettierignore` file along with the `.prettier` file you already have

Comment: @AndrewNolan if I'm not mistaken if i add file-name in prettierignore it will disable for file prettier formating, i dont want like so