# How can I modify how Prettier formats JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prettier

Prettier formats classes like this:

```
class Foo {
  bar = 1
}
```

I want to change this behavior to

```
class Foo {

  bar = 1
}
```

How can I write a Prettier Plugin or something that modifies a single behavior?

Related:

- [How can I prevent prettier behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60813712/340760)

Comment: That is uglifying the prettifier...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to quote the [Prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html):

> Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish. It is opinionated.

So, short answer: you can't.

A few options do exist (you can see them in the linked docs), but only serve as either compatibility fixes or due to "high demand", but I would not expect any functionality of the kind you're looking for to ever be added.

Edit:

A full list of available options can be found [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)